# Trying to write these arrays into a buffer and a table array, what am I missing?

Tags: c, arrays

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char * article[] = {
    "the",
    "a",
    "one",
    "some",
    "any"
};
char * noun[] = {
    "boy",
    "girl",
    "dog",
    "town",
    "car"
};
char * verb[] = {
    "drove",
    "jumped",
    "ran",
    "walked",
    "skipped"
};
char * preposition[] = {
    "to",
    "from",
    "over",
    "under",
    "on"
};
char sent[80] = "";
strcat(sent, article[rand() % 5]);
strcat(sent, verb[rand() % 5]);
strcat(sent, preposition[rand() % 5]);
strcat(sent, noun[rand() % 5]);

printf("%c", sent);
}
```

so I've written out the individual array to make random sentences. now I am trying to figure how to set these up into a table that has each array iterating 20 times to make a paragraph.

Comment: First  ,`printf("%c", sent);` **->** `printf("%s", sent);` .

Comment: So you want us to write the code for you?

Comment: You don't need a table, just print each sentence one after another. You *do* know how to use loops, and the different kinds of loops you can make in C?

Comment: FYI - to use `rand` properly You have to call `srand` as well.

Comment: figured it out, thanks guys

Comment: You are missing indention and the `const` keyword, to begin with.

Answer (score 1):

```
printf("%c", sent);
```

Prints only a single character, change it to:

```
printf("%s", sent);
```

This prints all characters in sent until the null terminator `\0`

Btw: If you want your `rand()` calls to return not the same thing every time, you need to call `srand()` before to initialise the basis for `rand()` to calculate its values. Typically this is done with system time as parameter or something similar to get different sets of `rand()` values every time the program is executed.

An example of using `srand()` to make sure you get a set of different `rand()` values every time you run the program would be implementing it using the c library function `time()` from the `time.h` library.

```
  srand((unsigned) time(&t));
```

Note `srand()` takes an unsigned int as input, to seed the algorhitm that calculates the (seemingly random) numbers for `rand()`